# Paste in textarea without special chars

Tags: javascript, html

I have some js function what don't allow few special characters, chars etc...
Some users using paste and with paste all chars and special characters are allowed.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
          //called when key is down
          $("#recipient").bind("keydown", function (event) {
            if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 188 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||

        // Allow: Ctrl+C
        (event.keyCode == 67 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||

        // Allow: Ctrl+V
        (event.keyCode == 86 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||



        // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
              // let it happen, don't do anything
              return;
        } else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
           });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="recipient" name="recipient" required="required" minlength="9">
```

This textarea is for phonenumber, it need to be like : 123123123. How change code to dont paste phonenumber with "-" or spaces if someone paste number "123-123-123" or "123 123 123"?

Comment: form where `</code>` comes in the end of ur block?

Comment: There's a "paste" event.

Comment: @Pointy it is "Ctrl+V" but it allows to paste phonenumber with "-" or spaces

Comment: You can use the "input" event

Comment: not like `bind("paste", function (event)`? Was trying like this but it didn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: You could use `.replace()` to filter nonnumeric into empty string and use `input` instead of `keydown` to get the correct value of current input

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
      //called when key is down
      $("#recipient").bind("input", function (event) {
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 188 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
    (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||

    // Allow: Ctrl+C
    (event.keyCode == 67 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||

    // Allow: Ctrl+V
    (event.keyCode == 86 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||



    // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
          // let it happen, don't do anything
          return;
    } else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
            event.preventDefault();
            
        }
        console.log(event.target.value)
        var numeric = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, '')//replace non-numeric into empty string
        console.log('numeric', numeric)   
        $('#recipient').val(numeric)
    }
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="recipient" name="recipient" required="required" minlength="9">
```

Comment: Great, it work. Can u add "," to allowed chars (comma)? I use it to seperate numbers.

Comment: if you want to allow comma, you can change the line to `var numeric = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, '')`. Notice that , is inside the [^] list

Comment: Unserstand now :) Thx @Alvin

Comment: seeing my input appearing then getting deleted gives me a poor user experience IMO

Comment: @Pac0 Thanks for pointing out, I've updated the snippet to use `input` instead of `keyup`

Comment: @AlvinTheodora much better :) ! +1

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the most simple and clear way is to use a regex to replace invalid characters:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#recipient").bind("input", function (event) {
    $('#recipient').val($('#recipient').val().replace(/\D/g,""))
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="recipient" name="recipient" required="required" minlength="9">
```

Comment: Clearest answer to me. Does allow copy pasting, does not show invalid characters before deleting them, does restrict everything but numbers.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript has a more simpler solution.**

For formatting your phone number *in real time* as the user types, you can just get the values from the input box and then use,

```
input.oninput = function() {}
```

OR

For formatting your phone number *stored in the clipboard*, you can get the values from the clipboard by using

```
input.onpaste = function(event){}
```

You can make the functions that I've used smaller by removing the tempText & formattedText variables if you like, I used only them for code legibility and for the convenience of the user to use the variables elsewhere on the code.

```js
/* Function 1 */
input.oninput = function() {
  var regExpr = /[^0-9,^,]/g; //If you don't want ',' comma then remove ^, from the code between [ ]
  var tempText = input.value;
  var formattedText = tempText.replace(regExpr, "");
  result.innerHTML = formattedText;
};

/* Function 2 */
input.onpaste = function(event) {
  var regExpr = /[^0-9,^,]/g; //If you don't want ',' comma then remove ^, from the code between [ ]
  var tempText = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  var formattedText = tempText.replace(regExpr, "");
  result.innerHTML = formattedText;
};
```

```css
/*Has nothing to do with the paste formatting*/

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 80vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #222;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

#input {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="centerAll">
    <form>
      <label><b>Enter Phone Number</b></label><br/>
      <input type="phone" id="input" placeholder="Enter Phone Number...">
      <br/>
      <br/> Copy paste this:<br/>123-123-123,123<br/>
      <br/> Entered Phone number is:<br/>
      <span id="result"></span>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>
```

I hope this helps...

Peace

Comment: I don't think the link to your blog  add any relevant information to your answer. I'd suggest removing this from your post (both the text and the "visit me" link in code snippet. (self-advertisement is welcome on your profile description / "developer story", though)